# jQuery ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, dropdown

I have a simple jquery function that reflects the selected value of a dropdown to textbox but the problem is that the console says that my function was undefined. I put the function inside the onchange event of the dropdown. Please note that all of my jquery functions was on the bottom of the page..

and here is the dropdown:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Operation</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="operationName" name="operationName">
       <option value="">-SELECT-</option>
        <?php
         foreach($operation as $val)
         {
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $val['OperationName'];?>"><?php echo $val['OperationName'];?></option>
          <?php
         }
      ?>
      </select>
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('operation');?></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deldays" name="deldays" 
          value="" />
```

this is the operation array model

function getDeliveryDays($str)
    {
        $this->db->select('DeliveryDays');
        $this->db->from('operation');
        $this->db->where('OperationName',$str);
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }

this is the controller:

```
public function getDays()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('q');
    $data['days'] = $this->wip_model->getDeliveryDays($id);

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I took the working in my other project and use it in my current project but still the same result and when I inspect it in the dev tools, the said script is missing in view source but it's present in IDE:

this is the code:

```
function showDeliveryDay(operation)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('wip/getDays/');?>",
            data: {q:operation},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    }
```

[image]

Thanks in advance....

Comment: what do you mean by before html? I put all of my jquery functions at the bottom of the page before the closing body.

Answer (score 1):

Does you put the function inside `domready`? If so, remove that and placed it outside like so :

```
<script>
  function showDays() {
     var x = document.getElementById("operationName").value;
     document.getElementById("deldays").innerHTML = x;
  }

 // domready here
 $(function(){...}); // or $(document).ready(function(){...});     
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that dom ready but same results still prompts that the function is undefined that's why I revert to simple script but still the same outcome...

Comment: So, you tried already put outside ondomready? Usually those errors come from that case. Can you reproduce code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I just followed this tutorial in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: That tutorial working great. Can you post the whole js code between `<script></script>` tag that you make so far.

Comment: I tried the code of WsdmLabs but it display nothing on the textbox and also I am using the new version of jquery library jquery-1.12.0.min.js if it does affect the whole process....

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are including your `jquery` in your code. try this:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {    
 jQuery( "#operationName" ).change(function() {
     var pVal = jQuery("#operationName").val();
     jQuery("#deldays").val(pVal);     
     });  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Operation</label>
<select class="form-control" id="operationName" name="operationName">
<option value="">-SELECT-</option>


<option value="one">1</option>
<option value="two">2</option>
<option value="three">3</option>

</select>
<span class="text-danger"></span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="deldays" name="deldays" 
value="" />

</div>
```

Comment: I am using the new jquery library or i must use the one that you mention?

Comment: I tried the code and it's working if it's just as it is but I am loading my options value from database and when I modified the code with data from db, it's not working.....

Comment: @SilverRay: than plz show the actual code in your  question plz

Comment: that's the actual code already that I post in my question... please see my poost....

Comment: @SilverRay: in your code plz remove onchange="showDays()" from select box

Comment: Please check the post I updated it and add the model for operations

Comment: @SilverRay: its working fine?? print_r($data['operation']);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104368/discussion-between-devpro-and-silverray).

Comment: @SilverRay: please add ending </div> in html

Comment: I just post the code snippet of the project that I am working and I assure you it is with ending div...

Comment: @SilverRay: well its not an issue, plz come on chat

Comment: @SilverRay: i have sent u a solution in chat

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this code

**Html**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Operation</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="operationName" name="operationName">
       <option value="">-SELECT-</option>


          <option value="one">1</option>
               <option value="two">2</option>
                    <option value="three">3</option>

      </select>
          <span class="text-danger"></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deldays" name="deldays" 
          value="" />
```

**Js code**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {    
     jQuery('#operationName').on('change', function(){    
     var p=jQuery(this).val();
     jQuery("#deldays").val(p);     
     });   

});
```

You can view [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/tenigada/nk94za1d/)

Comment: I tried you code no errors on console but it doesn't display anything in textbox....

Comment: I tried using your code with foreach and I am having an error but when I replace it with while loop it works perfectly using plain php but I don't know how when using codeigniter...